# Puppeteer PDF rendering wrong

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to print a PDF of an HTML using Puppeteer.

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

The first snapshot is from the PDF Puppeteer generated and the second snapshot is from the screenshot Puppeteer generated.

The rendering of graph canvas is proper in both normal HTML and screenshot, but not in the PDF.

Please help me out!

This is the code that I wrote

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Webpage {
    static async generatePDF() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--ignore-certificate-errors'], ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']});
        let page = await browser.newPage(); // Puppeteer can only generate pdf in headless mode.

    await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 960, deviceScaleFactor: 1});
        await page.goto("url", { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 30000 });
    await page.screenshot({path: "./screenshot.png"});
        const config = {
            path: '/home/haltdos/test.pdf',
            format: 'A3',
            printBackground: true,
        margin: {
                top: '3cm',
                bottom: '1cm',
                left: '1cm',
                right: '1cm'
            }
        };


        await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
        await page.pdf(config);
        await browser.close();
    }
}

Webpage.generatePDF();
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. but I would like my pdf to be exact like my html webpage instead of showing overflowing content. And I have also ensured that my website is responsive, and the content never overflows. Then why is the PDF showing like that!